# Kendo combo box when open in full screen mode becomes not selectable

Tags: angular, kendo-combobox

I am using kendo combo box. Whenever I make a particular div full screen, dropdown list of combobox present in it appears but it is unselectable.
Code for kendo Combo box:

```
<kendo-combobox
   id="chartcomboBoxId"
   [data]="data"
   [(value)]="selectedValue"
   [textField]="'desc'"
   [valueField]="'name'"
   [valuePrimitive]="true"
   (valueChange)="handleValueChange($event)"
   style="font-size: 10px; padding-top:2px; padding-left: 2px; 
         z-index:2147483648 !important;"
   *ngIf="data">
</kendo-combobox>
```

I have made the z-index max so that the list appears, otherwise the list was not appearing above the window in full screen mode.

code for making the div fullscreen:

```
public fullScreen() {
    const container = document.getElementById('container');
    if (container .requestFullscreen) {
        container .requestFullscreen();
    } else if (container .webkitRequestFullscreen) {
        container .webkitRequestFullscreen();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **appendTo** property of the **popupSettings** object set to **'component'**.  This way you specify that popup should be appended to the component instead of the root of the app (which is default). Also you may want to check this [`kendo documentation`](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/api/PopupSettings/)

```
 <kendo-combobox
     id="chartcomboBoxId"
     [data]="data"
     [(value)]="selectedValue"
     [textField]="'desc'"
     [valueField]="'name'"
     [valuePrimitive]="true"
     (valueChange)="handleValueChange($event)"
     [popupSettings]="{appendTo: 'component'}" <!--  <===  This line is a solution-->
     *ngIf="data">
</kendo-combobox>
```